# Sort algo for Pivoting a Matrix - How to make sure that non zero elements are on diagonal?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, matrix

I want to sort matrix so that non zero elements are on the diagonal. I want to pivot the matrix to solve linear equations. But to make sure everything is working, I have to have it sorted before my algo can do that.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package positioning;

/**
 *
 * @author Andreas
 */
public class lineareq {
    public static double[][] gaussjordan(double[][] mat){
        //http://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/pivot.html

        double factor1 =0;
        double factor2 =0;


        for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){

            factor1 = mat[i][i];
            if(factor1!=0){
                for(int j=0; j<mat.length; j++){
                    factor2 = mat[j][i];
                    if(i!=j && factor2!=0){
                        System.out.println(factor1+";"+factor2);
                        for(int k=0; k<mat.length+1; k++){
                            mat[j][k] = factor1*mat[j][k]-factor2*mat[i][k];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
            factor1=mat[i][i];
            if(mat[i][i]!=0){
                for(int j=0; j<mat.length+1; j++){
                    if(mat[i][j]!=0){
                        mat[i][j]=mat[i][j]/factor1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return mat;
    }


    public static double[][] mat3x3(double[][] mat){

        int[]   diagon      = new int[mat.length];
        int[]   diagony     = new int[mat.length];
        int[]   checkx      = new int[mat.length];
        int[]   checky      = new int[mat.length];
        int[]   changer      = new int[mat.length];
        int     checkcount  = 0;
        int[][] find = new int[mat.length][mat[0].length-1];

        for(int i=0; i<find.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<find[i].length; j++){
                if(mat[i][j]!=0){
                    find[i][j] = 1;
                    diagon[j] = diagon[j]+1;
                    diagony[i] = diagony[i]+1;
                }
//                System.out.print(find[i][j]+";");
            }
//            System.out.println();
        }
/*
        for(int i=0; i<diagon.length; i++){
            System.out.print(diagon[i]+";");
        }
        System.out.println("xxx");
        for(int i=0; i<diagony.length; i++){
            System.out.print(diagony[i]+";");
        }
        System.out.println("yyy");
 */

        int count = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<=diagon.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<diagon.length; j++){
                if(diagon[j]==i){
//                    System.out.println("x"+i+";"+j+";"+diagon[j]);

                    int k=0;
                    int stop=0;
                    while(k<diagon.length && stop==0){
//                        System.out.println(find[k][j]);
                        if(find[k][j]==1 && checkx[j]==0 && checky[k]==0){
//                            System.out.println("t");

                            changer[j] = k;
                            checkx[j]=1;
                            checky[k]=1;
                            stop=1;
                        }
                        k=k+1;
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int j=0; j<diagony.length; j++){
                if(diagony[j]==i){
//                    System.out.println("y"+i+";"+j+";"+diagony[j]);

                    int k=0;
                    int stop=0;
                    while(k<diagon.length && stop==0){
//                        System.out.println(find[j][k]);
                        if(find[j][k]==1 && checkx[k]==0 && checky[j]==0){
//                            System.out.println("t");

                            changer[k] = j;
                            checkx[k]=1;
                            checky[j]=1;
                            stop=1;
                        }
                        k=k+1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

//        System.out.println();
/*
        for(int i=0; i<changer.length; i++){
            System.out.print(changer[i]+";");
        }
        System.out.println();
 */

        double[][] mat_change = new double[mat.length][mat[0].length];
        for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<mat[i].length; j++){
                mat_change[i][j] = mat[changer[i]][j];
            }
        }

        return mat_change;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use an existing library?

Comment: @trashgod probably because it's homework.

Comment: it's no homework, it's for me and I want to know how that is done.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, one of the  [`Arrays.sort()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28double%5B%5D%29) methods that takes `double` may serve. For study, I like [JScience](http://jscience.org/) and [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/). The former admits `DenseMatrix<Rational>`, which may prove useful for [*Gauss–Jordan elimination*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination). For debugging, you'll need an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that includes test cases.